Excel VBA copy Date into Cell Range, after pasting DataSet from another WB, but keeping the old data
I want to Copy a set of Data from another Workbook and my code copies it under the last set. Im Copying from Sheet "Übersciht" to Sheet "Daten". I want the date to be Pasted in every pasted row in "Daten" as soon as I paste the Data set
    Sub Schaltfläche1_Klicken()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim mWB As Workbook 'This Workbook
Dim dWB As Workbook 'Data Workbook

'set the Main Workbook
Set mWB = ThisWorkbook


Dim filePath As String
filePath = Application.GetOpenFilename

Debug.Print filePath

'Set the Data Workbook
Set dWB = Workbooks.Open(filePath)

Dim dataSh As Worksheet
Set dataSh = dWB.Sheets("Fuhrparksteuerung XLS Export")

'copy the Data Table
dataSh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy

'Paste the Data Table
mWB.Sheets("Übersicht").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

dWB.Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True



With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
     LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
   
    
 LastRow = Sheets("Daten").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Range("A4:M25").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Daten").Range("B" & LastRow)
   Sheets("Daten").Range("A" & LastRow) = Range("A2").Value


End Sub


I tried this code to copy/paste, but i need the Date from Cell A2 to be pasted into every pasted row in "Daten" Sheet .

It should look like this after pasting.

Please help me, thank you very much :)

Assign the date to a variable and keep pasting that in column A, change the value of the variable as the date changes.

@cybernetic.nomad Im new to coding and dont really know what to do... Can you tell how to do it please :)

Try the following to copy the the data from the "Übersicht" sheet below existing data in the "Daten" sheet:
LastRowU = mWB.Sheets("Übersicht").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
LastRowD = mWB.Sheets("Daten").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Daten").Range("A" & LastRowD & ":A" & LastRowD + LastRowU).Value = mWB.Sheets("Übersicht").Range("A2").Value
Sheets("Daten").Range("B" & LastRowD & ":M" & LastRowD + LastRowU).Value = mWB.Sheets("Übersicht").Range("B2:M" & LastRowU).Value

(Note: I did not test this code)

Now it just pastes the Date into 1 cell

Works fine for me. Is there data in column B of the Daten sheet when you use it to calculate the value of LastRow?

Consider getting rid of With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet /   LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row /     End With. ThisWorkbook refers to the workbook containing the macro and is probably not the one you want to use to calculate LastRow

When I press the button now it doens´t copy from one sheet to another, it just fills out Column A with the date and overwrites existing Dates... No, Column B has no Data when pasted.

Try using Sheets("Übersicht").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row maybe? In your question you state 'Copying from Sheet "Übersicht" to Sheet "Daten"' but that is not what your code does (it copies from the workbook you open to the "Übersicht" sheet)

Yes, exactly. It copies from an Workbook to "Übersicht", then i want data dataset to be Copied to "Daten" with the right Date. Because, tomorrow i want to import the same Table but different Data. It offsets the dataset by 1 to the right, so i have space for the dates...

Now it overwrite the existing data in Sheet "Daten"... maybe i didnt explain enough... The Sheet "Daten" is where all my data is gathered... so every time i press the button it pastes the new dataset under the last set in Sheet "Daten"

If you want to keep the existing data, you need to find the last row in "Daten" and insert starting there. Consider editing your question to clarify it.

I editted it. I hope its better now. Im sorry, im new to this stuff... can you just tell me the code to keep the data and just stacking the new ones? Im sorry to be such a noob xD

It kinda pastes offset.... but nevermind... isnt there a way to say "fill the empty cells beneath me with the value i have, if the cell on my right is not empty"?
